Maximum Sum of Vertices in DAG Excluding Directly Connected Vertices
How can I calculate the maximum possible sum of vertices in a weighted DAG excluding vertices directly connected by an edge? This is a vertex selection problem where each vertex has a weight.
In this first graph which is a tree rooted at A the answer would be 30. The vertices that are chosen to be part of the sum are B, E, F, H, and I. A and B cannot be both included since they are directly connected by an edge. The same applied to vertices C and D.
Link to Visualization of the First Graph
Edges:
A B
B C
B D
C E
C F
D H
D I

Weight of each vertex:
A 1
B 10
C 1
D 1
E 5
F 5
H 5
I 5

In this second graph the answer would be 40 and the vertices included in the sum would be A, B, E, and F. C is skipped over since either A and B are included or only C is included. D is skipped over since either E and F are included or only D is included.
Link to Visualization of the Second Graph

Edges:
A C
B C
C D
D E
D F

Weight of each vertex:
A 10
B 10
C 1
D 2
E 10
F 10

An inefficient O((2^V)E) approach would be to

Find all subsets of vertices in the graph
Remove all the subsets with adjacent vertices
Calculate the sum of the weights of the vertices in each subset
Return the subset with the highest sum

Can something like the Viterbi algorithm be used to solve this problem? Since the graph can be topologically sorted only the adjacent two levels need to be considered when deciding if a vertex should be included in the sum.

That's basically maximum-weight Independent Set problem, right? Does making it a directed graph really change anything, or am I missing something else?

@tobias_k Changing the graph to be undirected does not change the problem

@tobias_k is there a solutions to the maximum-weight Independent Set problem in polynomial time when the graph does not have any cycles?

I think for a tree, as in your examples, you can use some DP or divide&conquer approach, but note that in general a DAG is not necessarily a tree if you remove the "directed" part.

@tobias_k I know there is a linear time algorithm for when the graph is a tree but that algorithm would not work in the second example. Also a DAG is not a tree even if it is directed.

From https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04761 it seems that there is a polynomial time algorithm to solve MWIS in a graph without a cycle
